# Text '2022-10-30T13%3A28%3A41.530530' could not be parsed at index 10

Tags: java, spring, date, localdatetime

I send a request from the main service to the statistics service, where I send parameters, including the encoded date

[image: the request looks like this]

here is the code in the statistics service that formats the date

```
default Specification<View> getSpecificationByParams(StatsSearchParams params) {
   return (((root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
      List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
      DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

      if (params.getUris() != null) {
         for (String uri : params.getUris()) {
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.in(root.get("uri")).value(uri));
         }
      }
      if (params.getStart() != null) {
         predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(
               root.get("timestamp"),
               LocalDateTime.parse(params.getStart(), formatter)));
      }
      if (params.getEnd() != null) {
         predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(
               root.get("timestamp"),
               LocalDateTime.parse(params.getEnd(), formatter)));
      }

      return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(Predicate[]::new));
   }));
```

when sending a request, I get an error with the following stack trace

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2022-10-30T13%3A28%3A41.530530' could not be parsed at index 10
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2046) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.stats.view.ViewRepository.lambda$getSpecificationByParams$ac66be10$1(ViewRepository.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.applySpecificationToCriteria(SimpleJpaRepository.java:879) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:813) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:798) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:505) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.stats.view.ViewRepository.searchStatsByParams(ViewRepository.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
```

how to format a string into a date correctly?

I tried adding @jsonformat(pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss")

Comment: That string is the URL encoded equivalent of `2022-10-30T13:28:41.530530`. You need to figure out why it is being provided in that format, or just decode it.

Comment: Even when URL-decoded, the string still won't match. After the date component your format string includes a space but the actual string contains a letter `T`.

Comment: Once URL decoded into `2022-10-30T13:28:41.530530`, forget about the formatter and just pass the string to the one-arg `LocalDateTime.parse(CharSequence)`. The string is in the [ISO 8501](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, the default for java.time classes, which is why you don’t need to specify any formatter.